# Adding local jar as dependency to maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have maven project where i need to add local jar as the dependency.

I have stored my jar into my maven folder using:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path\to\file\framework-0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=test -DartifactId=test  -Dversion=0.0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`

I have read that adding dependencty to POM file is deprecated ( didnt even work  for me ). So how should i include this dependency in my project? My settings.xml looks like:

```
<localRepository>C:\project\.m2</localRepository>
<mirrors>
       ....
</mirrors>

<servers>
    <server>
         ....
    </server>
    <server>
        ....
    </server>
</servers>
```

If i try to jusat use classes from the jar, Intelijj cannot find. So how should i add this dependency to my maven project?

Thanks for answers

Comment: maven system scope can help?

Comment: POM dependency can't deprecate, it's a fundamental concept of Maven projects.

Answer (score 2):

You installed the dependency in the local repository.

So you can use it as any other dependency by declaring it as `<dependency>` in the `<dependencies>` area of your `pom.xml`.

BTW: Don't use system scope.